# Where to store HMAC nonce on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, hmac, nonce

I'm building an API on Google's Firebase where my customers will pay for usage. One measure I'm taking to protect my customers from a man in the middle inflating their usage (and their bill) is a HMAC header with a request-time and expire time.

A man-in-the-middle could still do a repeat attack between those two times. Therefore I want to include a nonce in the HMAC. My problem is where to store the nonce. I could put them in Firestore with a [TTL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/ttl) longer than the nonce's expire time. (One extra read, write and delete per API request can fit in my budget.)

I'm worried that Firestore's "eventual consistency" would mean the nonce would not be found yet at the time of the man-in-the-middle attack. Is this a valid concern?

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about Firestore's eventual consistency, you could configure it in datastore mode:
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore#in_datastore_mode